# Can't impl a type trait requiring Debug for a type containing PhantomData

Tags: rust, type-traits

Given the following code ([Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=ad70fe340d2ac3f7b11dc49bfec7e3b9&version=stable&backtrace=0)):

```
use std::fmt::Debug;
use std::marker::PhantomData;

trait Herp: Debug {}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Derp<S: ?Sized> {
    phantom: PhantomData<S>
}

impl<S: ?Sized> Herp for Derp<S> {}
```

The following error occurs:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `S: std::fmt::Debug` is not satisfied
  --> src/...
   |
37 | impl<S: ?Sized> Herp for Derp<S> {}
   |                 ^^^^
   |
   = help: consider adding a `where S: std::fmt::Debug` bound
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::fmt::Debug` for `Derp<S>`
   = note: required by `Herp
```

I find this behaviour inappropriate because `Debug` is derived properly for `Derp` and `PhantomData<T>` should implement `Debug` regardless of type `T` ([docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/struct.PhantomData.html)). I also couldn't find anything else on my search that could apparently induce this error.

Why can't I implement a trait that requires Debug for a type containing a phantom?